# Is there a seasonal VARMAX model available in Python or R?

Tags: python, r, time-series

I have three similar time series that lend themselves well to the VARMAX model, but they also demonstrate seasonality. Is there a seasonal VARMAX model available in either Python or R? I'm aware of a seasonal VARMA available in R, [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/MTS/man/sVARMA.html), but it does not support exogenous variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a VARMAX algorithm in python: `statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX`. Here's the [documentaion](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.varmax.VARMAX.html).

But I don't think you could find sVARMAX.